# Unable to add custom domain to Github Pages site through Cloudflare

Tags: reactjs, dns, github-pages, cloudflare

This is not my first time using Cloudflare, but it is my first time doing a GH Pages <> Cloudflare setup.

I bought the domain through Google Domains and updated the DNS to route through Cloudflare. From there I added the CNAME file which can be seen in [this project](https://github.com/andy8052/my-website). I also set the custom domain in the settings tab to my desired domain (andychorlian.com). From there, I added [these two CNAME settings](https://i.gyazo.com/70b6bc225c74fce36e2a140970950afe.png) to Cloudflare.

I believe this should be everything I need to have my gh pages working with my custom domain, but when I go there all I see is the "React App" tab name and then a blank site. Could this be a react thing?

Comment: Just so you know, if you are using Cloudflare only to get HTTPS, [you don’t need Cloudflare](https://blog.github.com/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/).

Answer (score 1):

So turns out I am an idiot and didn't update the `homepage` field in `package.json`

Answer (score -1):

the github page repository name must be "youname.github.io"

your repository name is my-website ，so not work

this is my github page repository https://github.com/leinov/leinov.github.io

Comment: I don't believe it has to be. You can have project repositories which are not named that. It is able to host fine without a custom domain